# Does the phrase “apace with” mean “to keep pace with”?

Tags: adverbs

Merriam Webster says the below:

> Definition of apace with : going or advancing at the same rate as (something)
>
> *E.g. The company has been struggling to keep pace/apace with the latest developments*

But I’ve not seen this definition in other dictionaries like Oxford Advanced’s Learners Dictionary. Can someone kindly share if this is accurate?

Comment: Please provide an example sentence that you are wondering about, not just a phrase.

Comment: Hi, I’ve added a line break to make the example sentence more obvious, thank you

Comment: I've made a slight adjustment to the example to make the comparison clearer. If that is the issue you're asking about, just let it stand.

Comment: @Robusto What are the alternatives exactly? "The company has been struggling to keep pace with the latest developments" and The company has been struggling apace with the latest developments"? Or is the 2nd example supposed to be The company has been struggling to keep apace with the latest developments? It is not clear from the example. In comparisons like this it is best to spell out exactly the alternatives in separate full sentences.

Comment: @Mitch: Feel free to edit as you see fit. I'm just trying to get at what OP's issue is here, without actually answering the question in a comment.

Comment: I've never heard 'keep apace with', and M-W seems to be the only dictionary that gives this sense.

Comment: Here we are faced again with what Anton (high rep forum member) calls "gaps in the dictionary world". I myself have not heard it (i.e. keep apace with). But apparently it is not so uncommon. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+apace+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeep%20apace%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ckeep%20apace%20with%3B%2Cc0 and https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keep%20apace%20with%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: So what definition have you seen? Please do not refer to entries like that without providing them. This question should be asked on ELL, not here. Cheers.

Comment: @Lambie agreed about providing entries. disagreed about 'should be on ELL'. OK for ELL, but also very appropriate here.

Comment: [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+apace+of%2Ckeep+pace+with%2Ckeep+apace+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeep%20apace%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20pace%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20apace%20with%3B%2Cc0) may offer a fairer comment on idiomaticity / colligality.

Comment: It falls between "platypus" and "ugly cousin", so it does exist. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+apace+with%2Cugly+cousin

Comment: Hi all, thank you for all the help. It has been very useful, especially all the links provided. @jimm101 Can I ask what is the significance of the word showing up between “platypus” and “ugly cousin”?

Comment: @ConfusedEnglishLearner Nothing special, but they are familiar to almost any native speaker, and are in roughly the same neighborhood (at least a graph shows more than a flat line).

Answer (score 1):

This usage has been commonplace for nearly two centuries, at least regionally. The early uses seem to be in the form of *keep apace*. *Stay apace* being a less common version that appeared about 80 years later.

The following were gleaned from Elephind.

> 1851 - The Cornwall Chronicle (That's Cornwall California, in the off-chance there are others)
>
> Nor is the tone of
> moral feeling, in or out of cities, of a low,
> vicious, or evil character ; but as the diffi
> culties of subsistence accumulate, and want
> and famine approaches — as come it will to
> many — outrages will doubtless increase,
> and keep apace with tbe poverty and misery
> under which many thousands, I fear, are
> doomed to perish during the present wintry
> season of that country.

There were a few slightly earlier references from the American Midwest or Southwest, but the digitized text wasn't available.

> ... , where the national open championship opens it*, tumultuous three-day stand tQday. There are 6,709 yards of velvety greensward to be done in 7? -strokes by the player who would stay apace with par—approximately 100 yards more than at either Olympia fields or Winged Foot, where the last two opens have been held—but there is considerable more to the course .
>
> Page 11 [Newspaper Page] — Indianapolis Times — 10 July 1930
> Publication Title: Indianapolis Times
> Source: Indiana Digital Historic Newspaper Program (Indiana State Library)
> Country/State of Publication: Indiana, United States

> Speed Enables Press To Stay Apace Of War
>
> The Kent Stater, Volume XVII, Number 71, 18 February 1942

This one is interesting since it is oriented towards the idea of speed, but is used as a comparison to a benchmark.

> https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth283646/m1/1/zoom/?q=%22stay%20apace%22&resolution=2&lat=2703.1249999999995&lon=661.5
>
> However, Rotan enjoys a good water supply at this time with a 16 mile gravity flow pipe line from wells. It has been necessary to keep digging wells to stay apace of demand.
>
> April 20 1949.

The context here is a comparison to demand, and that doesn't carry any semantic sense of speed at all.

I leaned heavily on the *stay apace* version because I think it more clearly restricts the usage to the *abreast with* or *consistent with* sense. All the early examples appear to be American.

Personally, I have only ever used *apace* in this comparative sense. I had thought the earlier sense was obsolete.

After several hours of poking around, I did find one recent example where I'm reasonably confident that the writer meant *quickly*.

> The JCPOA puts a temporary lid on Iran’s uranium-enrichment and plutonium programs, but other nuclear developments – testing of more advanced centrifuges, stockpiling of uranium, and enhancing nuclear manufacturing infrastructure – continue apace. Developments on Tehran’s missile program therefore cannot be dealt with in isolation from its nuclear efforts.
> https://www.fdd.org/analysis/2017/02/08/irans-missile-tests-reveal-weaknesses-of-un-security-council-resolution/
> Olli Heinonen
> Foundation for Defense of Democracies

So I sampled other uses of *apace* in this context (JCPOA, P5+1) but only found the comparative use I am accustomed to. But the negotiations were largely an American thing, and the commentary above was from someone born in Finland.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MW is ahead of the game but only if you believe the dictum *"When enough people are wrong, they are right."*

A Google search for  **To keep apace of** and **to keep apace with** shows relatively frequent collocations. **Apace** (adverb) seems to be a substitute for the original noun "**pace**."

From Google:

**keep apace of**

> M&S digital lab brings nimble start up approach https://www.marketingweek.com › ms-digital-lab-bring...
> *Marks & Spencer has created its own in-house “digital lab” division to keep apace of developments that will make sure its business remains relevant to the ...*
>
> Forthcoming Events - Cinema Theatre Associationhttps://cinema-theatre.org.uk › visits-events › forthcomi...
> *Keeping apace of developments in the field of high-tech film exhibition, we are privileged to have a presentation about the latest IMAX installation at ...*
>
> Iron and Steelworks of the World - ProQuesthttps://search.proquest.com › openview
> by T Smith · 2002 — *An attempt has also been made to try and keep apace of developments in the USA with eight of the present 28 companies in Chapter 1 1 bankruptcy protection ...*
>
> PSS Across the UK | Port Skills and Safetyhttps://www.portskillsandsafety.co.uk › news › pss-acro...
> 24 Nov 2020 — *... automation of port operations and how PSS must stay apace of developments in this field in order to provide a well-rounded service.*

**to keep apace with**

> Who to follow on Twitter to keep apace with PropTechhttps://www.lendinvest.com › blog › whos-proptech-twi...
> 2 Sept 2016 — *Who to follow on Twitter to keep apace with PropTech. London PropTech is having its moment. If you're as keen as us to know what is going on ...*
>
> Quality childcare matters - Care Inspectorate Waleshttps://www.careinspectorate.wales › quality-childcare-...
> 24 Aug 2015 — *To do this we will continue to improve on our inspection methods and keep apace with modern practice to have a greater impact on improving ...*
>
> Stars of film criticism show how to keep apace with ... - Swissinfohttps://www.swissinfo.ch › eng › stars-of-film-criticism-...
> 12 Aug 2022 — *Stars of film criticism show how to keep apace with the changes in the industry. Debate with critic Laura Mulvey at Locfarno75 ...*
>
> Apace Synonyms & Antonymshttps://www.synonyms.com › synonym › apace
> ... upbeat about credit demand, but we'll have to see how the capitalization of banks evolves and whether it can keep apace with this appetite for credit.
>
> SuperGroup to open new fulfilment centre to keep apace with ...https://www.retail-week.com › 5048235.article
> SuperGroup to open new Burton-on-Trent fulfilment centre to keep apace with growing sales. By Nicola Harrison15 April 2013. No comments.

Comment: Hi @Greybeard, thank you for the answer. So, people used the word wrongly many times… Can I ask if Merriam Webster is a reliable dictionary, and if no, what is a more reliable dictionary to refer to?

Comment: @ConfusedEnglishLearner MW is quite good and very useful for American English. It is always relatively up-to-date - I would give it 7½/10.